# SharePoint 2010 - central admin - cannot delete user profile

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am farm Admin of SharePoint 2010 environment. i am trying to delete some user profile from central admin but it is giving me "access denied" error.

This is what i am doing.
1. open central admin
2. go to application management then manage service application
3. select user profile service application. (note that i have given explicit permission to myself for this service by clicking 'administrators' and 'permissions' icon on the top of the page)
4. select Manage user profiles
4. search for specific profile and the delete. here i am getting access denied error.

can anyone tell me why i am getting access denied error.

Answer (score -1):

Try to restart the User Profile Synchronization Service.

Or use PowerShell script to delete user profile.

```
$spSite=Get-SPSite "http://servername"
$ctx=[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPServiceContext]::GetContext($spSite)
$userName = "spUserToDelete";
$userProfileMgr = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]
$upm=New-Object $userProfileMgr($ctx)
$upm.RemoveUserProfile($userName)
```